# How to convert char* to PRUnichar *

Tags: c++, xpcom

I need to pass `char*` to XPCOM function but that function accepts `PRUnichar *`. How to convert from `char*` to  `PRUnichar *` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [nsAutoString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsAutoString#AssignWithConversion).

Comment: Note that you only want that if you are absolutely sure your data is ASCII. To quote the doc you linked to: "assign/append/insert with _LOSSY_ conversion".

Comment: I prefer to not make that assumption.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a UTF-8 string then you can use NS_ConvertUTF8toUTF16 or CopyUTF8toUTF16. If you have some other encoding then you'll need to use nsICharsetConverterManager or some other API to convert to something sane:
http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/intl/uconv/idl/nsICharsetConverterManager.idl

The XPCOM string guide has a good reference on this:
https://developer.mozilla.org/En/XPCOM:Strings#Unicode_Conversion_ns*CString_vs._ns*String

Answer (score 1):

In which character set is your char* ?